# Opening a related file in vim

Tags: vim

In Vim, how can I get the name of the current file, pass it to an external script, read the output of the script (which will be a filename) and open that file in vim in a new buffer? For example, I'm editing `lib/foo.rb` and want to open `spec/foo_spec.rb` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using backtick expansion:

```
:e `foo.sh %`
```

1. `%` is expanded by Vim to the current buffer name,
2. then the backtick expression is evaluated in a sub-shell,
3. and the result is used as argument for `:e`.

See `:help expand()` for `%`, and `:help backtick-expansion` for… backtick expansion.